# How can I compress images before storing them ? Android to Server

Tags: php, android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an app in which a user can upload a picture. I'm uploading the picture to the server in a folder and I store in the database the path to that picture (->http://server.com/images/picture1.jpeg). This is how I upload a picture:

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . $extension;
        $target_path = $target_path . basename($newfilename);
        $imagepath = "http://server.com/images/" . basename($newfilename);
        ...
        }
```

How can I store the image, but compressed. I saw that any picture that I upload to facebook is around 100 KB. How can I achieve something similar or what would you recommend ?

Comment: What about creating a local compressed version of the picture before uploading? Android offers enough functionality for image processing. Simply create a 90% JPEG and see how big it is; otherwise use PNG which is not only lossless but also very compact.

Comment: I would take a look in using webP https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/?hl=en